# Save DateTime in US format and Display in UK format

Tags: c#

My server is in US and my Client is in India.

I tried writing a function which can return UK date when I pass US format and Vice versa. but it don't work.

```
// client culture
System.Globalization.CultureInfo UKcultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb");
// server culture
System.Globalization.CultureInfo UScultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
public DateTime ReturnUKDate(string date)
{
            return DateTime.Parse(date, UKcultureInfo);
}
```

but when I pass ReturnUKDate("12/29/2012")

I get this error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Where do you save the date value to? Database, XML, or other (please specify)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should always **save your dates in UTC** - not a local time format. Also do not save dates as strings if you can (unavoidable for XML I guess), but strongly typed, e.g. SQL Server supports a `DateTime` data type. From UTC you can then convert to any local you want - *for display purposes*.

For parsing a particular date string with a known format you can the use `ParseExcact` or `TryParseExcact` so you can pass in the exact format string.

Comment: You shouldn't *always* save in UTC. For example, if I want to represent a recurring event which occurs at 7pm local time every week, then to find out the instant on which that occurs I need to store the time zone, and it makes sense to store the local time too rather than some arbitrary UTC value to convert.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Why couldn't you derive the local event time from the UTC time stored?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're passing in a US style date and specifying a UK culture.

This works

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("12/29/2012", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));
```

and so does this

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("29/12/2012", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb"));
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do is correct as pointed out in other answers.